# Excel formula to determine distinct list and sort the values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet where users enter various year-end data. Each year may have multiple records. Let's say column A contains the year. Sometimes the users don't enter the years in order (e.g. 2015, 2014, 2013, etc.) and sometimes there are blank spaces between years. I am trying to use formulas to create a summary table of the data by year.

Some example input is (say this is column A):

```
+---+------+
|   | A    |
+---+------+
| 1 |      |
+---+------+
| 2 | 2013 |
+---+------+
| 3 | 2015 |
+---+------+
| 4 |      |
+---+------+
| 5 | 2014 |
+---+------+
| 6 | 2015 |
+---+------+
| 7 | 2015 |
+---+------+
| 8 |      |
+---+------+
```

And my desired output would be (say in column C):

```
+---+------+
|   | C    |
+---+------+
| 1 | 2015 |
+---+------+
| 2 | 2014 |
+---+------+
| 3 | 2013 |
+---+------+
```

Notice how there are no duplicates, blanks are removed, and the order is sorted by year descending.

I know I will need to use an array formula, and in fact I have one that *mostly* works (an array formula with a mix of index, match, sum, and countif). The issue arises when the first cell (A1 in my example input above) is empty, the formula fails, but otherwise it works. Since I cannot reliably say people will always start their data in cell A1 I need to correct this.

I cannot use a macro (which is more my style in Excel, advanced formulas definitely are not) because the requirement is that it is saved as a .xlsx file.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why not show your formula that *mostly* works?

Comment: To be honest it is complicated, I wanted to show that I did do some research, but I didn't want to influence peoples' solutions too much. Personally when I get set down a specific path I find it hard to deviate so I prefer to omit such information in situations like this but I understand how it would've been helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **C1** enter:

```
=MAX(A:A)
```

and in **C2** enter the array formula:

```
=MAX(IF(A:A<C1,A:A))
```

and copy down.

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Sorry. I know I've said this before, but I really do think that we can't assume that OPs will know to amend the full column references accordingly. And if they don't then, unless the OP really has data extending all the way to row 1048576, as they stand those formulas are not at all to be recommended.

Comment: Never even occurred to be to do something like this. Appears to work just fine! Many thanks.